# I am using JavaCV and OpenCV245.This is working on Windows 7,but don't working on Windows XP. How I can this implementation?

Tags: java, opencv, tesseract, javacv

I am using JavaCV and OpenCV245.This is working on Windows 7,but don't working on Windows XP.
How I can this implementation ?

Comment: For those who voted to close this as "unclear what you are asking", please explain what is unclear.  It is pretty obvious what the OP is asking ... if you know what Tesseract is and what OCR is.  (And if you don't ... then please try to find out *before* you hit the vote-to-close button.  Be fair now.)

Answer (score 3):

From my brief reading of the [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_add_just_one_character_or_one_font_to_my_favourite_lang), the solution is to retrain the Tesseract engine using datasets that include examples of the characters that you need:

References:

- http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract2
- http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3